# Is it possible to check if the column exists in the table in another database, dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So I'm in situation when I have to know if the column exists in the table in another database. I can't switch database context and I cannot use dynamic SQL, because I have to do it inside scalar function.

How can I do this?

I can find if the table exists, by checking `object_id('<database name>.<schema name>.<table name>')`, but I cannot find a way to check if the column exists.

It seems not possible to do with `object_id()` function, there's no type for column - [`sys.objects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)

**update**. I totally forgot to mention that `<database name>`, `<schema name>`, `<table name>` and `<column name>` are VARIABLES, so it's not possible to use `information_schema` or `sys` tables/view. So it should be something like this

```
declare
    @database_name nvarchar(128),
    @schema_name nvarchar(128),
    @table_name nvarchar(128),
    @column_name nvarchar(128)

if object_id(@database_name + '.' + @schema_name + '.' + @table_name) is not null
    print 'Table exists'
else
    print 'Table does not exist'

if <??? how to check if column exists ???>
    print 'Column exists'
else
    print 'Column does not exist'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the only way I've found so far is to check [`col_length()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188732.aspx) function. It looks like some kind of hack, but it works consistently, I've checked this versus dynamic SQL for set of databases.

```
declare
    @database_name nvarchar(128),
    @schema_name nvarchar(128),
    @table_name nvarchar(128),
    @column_name nvarchar(128),
    @object_name nvarchar(max)

select @object_name = @database_name + '.' + @schema_name + '.' + @table_name

if object_id(@object_name) is not null
    print 'Table exists'
else
    print 'Table does not exist'

if col_length(@object_name, @column_name) is not null
    print 'Column exists'
else
    print 'Column does not exist'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
if exists(  select top 1 1
                from    Sys.tables    t
                join    Sys.columns   c
                    on  t.object_id = c.object_id
                where  t.name =  'Your_Table_name'
                    and c.name = 'Your_Column_name')
    select  'Your Cloumn Exists'
    else
    select 'Your Cloumn Does not Exist'
```

Comment: hi please check the updated version, I miss the main point of the question, I have to do this dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the column is defined, you can use the `information_schema` functions:

```
select count(*) as IsExists
from <databasename>.information_schema.columns c
where table_schema = '<schema>' and table_name = '<tablename>' and
      column_name = '<columnname>'
```

A value of 0 means the column does not exist.  A value of 1 means that it does.

Comment: hi please check the updated version, I miss the main point of the question, I have to do this dynamically

Answer (score 0):

To check if the column exists in any table of the database, you can use below script

```
-- with partial column name: 

        IF EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            where column_name like '%SEARCH_TEXT%'
        )
            PRINT 'Column found'
        ELSE
            PRINT 'Column not found'


    -- To search with exact text
        IF EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            where column_name = 'SEARCH_TEXT'
        )
            PRINT 'Column found'
        ELSE
            PRINT 'Column not found'
```

To see the details of the column just run the script inside if statement